# Python Crash Course Chapter 9 - eric.privileges.privileges

Tags: python

This code is from python crash course 9.8.

```
class User():
    """Represent a simple user profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the user."""
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.location = location.title()
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        """Display a summary of the user's information."""
        print("\n" + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name)
        print("  Username: " + self.username)
        print("  Email: " + self.email)
        print("  Location: " + self.location)

    def greet_user(self):
        """Display a personalized greeting to the user."""
        print("\nWelcome back, " + self.username + "!")

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        """Increment the value of login_attempts."""
        self.login_attempts += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Reset login_attempts to 0."""
        self.login_attempts = 0

class Admin(User):
    """A user with administrative privileges."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the admin."""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, email, location)

        # Initialize an empty set of privileges.
        self.privileges = Privileges()


class Privileges():
    """A class to store an admin's privileges."""

    def __init__(self, privileges=[]):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("\nPrivileges:")
        if self.privileges:
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print("- " + privilege)
        else:
            print("- This user has no privileges.")


eric = Admin('eric', 'matthes', 'e_matthes', 'e_matthes@example.com', 'alaska')
eric.describe_user()

eric.privileges.show_privileges()

print("\nAdding privileges...")
eric_privileges = [
    'can reset passwords',
    'can moderate discussions',
    'can suspend accounts',
    ]
eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges
eric.privileges.show_privileges()
```

What does the comment "To initialize  an empty set of strings" mean? 
What does `self.privileges =Privileges()` do? 
Also, what does `eric.privileges.privileges` mean? 
Why are there two dots on privileges, won't just `eric.privileges` trigger the value?

Answer (score 1):

`self.privileges = Privileges()` creates a `Privileges` object and assigns it to `self.privileges`.

`eric` is an `Admin` object created via

```
eric = Admin('eric', 'matthes', 'e_matthes', 'e_matthes@example.com', 'alaska')
```

so `eric.privileges` accesses the `Privileges` object stored in `eric` via the `self.privileges = Privileges()` line mentioned before and `eric.privileges.privileges` accesses the privileges list within the object (see the `self.privileges = privileges` line in the `__init__` function of the `Privileges` class). It's just digging deeper into them.